# display grid of data in bash

Tags: bash, grid

would like to get an opinion on how best to do this in bash, thank you

for x number of servers, each has it's own list of replication agreements and their status.. it's easy to run a few commands and get this data, ex;

get servers, output (setting/variable in/from a local config file);

```
. ./ldap-config ; echo "$MASTER $REPLICAS"
dc1-server1 dc1-server2 dc2-server1 dc2-server2 dc3...
```

for dc1-server1, get agreements, output;

```
ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dspw) list -v $SERVER.$DOMAIN | grep ': replica' | sed 's/: replica//'
dc2-server1
dc3-server1
dc4-server1
```

for dc1-server1, get agreement status codes, output;

```
ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dspw) list -v $SERVER.$DOMAIN | grep 'status: Error (' | sed -e 's/.*status: Error (//' -e 's/).*//'
0
0
18
```

so output would be several columns based on the 'get servers' list with each 'replica: status' under each server, for that server

looking to achieve something like;

```
dc2-server1: 0   dc2-server2: 0   dc1-server1: 0  ...
dc3-server1: 0   dc3-server2: 18  dc3-server1: 13 ...
dc4-server1: 18  dc4-server2: 0   dc4-server1: 0  ...
```

Comment: Please add the three command you used to generate the output.

Comment: hmm, the commands are a bit specific to the env.. for the servers list (get servers), these are in a source'd config file, which has different names/quantity depending on the env/cluster, ex; SERVERS="dc1-server1 dc2-server2 ..." Then for each server, parse a (ipa) command to get the replication agreements server names (get agreements) and also parse the command to get replication status for those servers (get agreement status codes).

Comment: Issue really, the data comes in as various columns to be assigned to vars during the data collection phase, but then has to be printed onscreen a row at a time for all the various servers.. kind of in a grid format.

Comment: Data all comes from; 'ipa-replica-manage list -v $SERVER'

Answer (score 0):

Generally `eval` is considered evil. Nevertheless, I'm going to use it.

`paste` is handy for printing files side-by-side.
Bash process substitutions can be used where you'd use a filename.

So, I'm going to dynamically build up a paste command and then eval it

I'm going to use `get.sh` as a placeholder for your mystery commands.

```sh
cmd="paste"

while read -ra servers; do
    for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
        cmd+=" <(./get.sh \"$server\" agreements | sed 's/\$/:/')"
        cmd+=" <(./get.sh \"$server\" status)"
    done
done < <(./get.sh servers)

eval "$cmd" | column -t
```

Comment: . ~/.ldap-config

cmd="paste"

while read -ra servers; do
    for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
        cmd+=" <(ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v `hostname` | grep ': replica' | sed 's/: replica//'
        cmd+=" <(ipa-replica-manage -p $(cat ~/.dsp) list -v $(hostname) | grep 'status: Error (' | sed -e 's/.*status: Error (//' -e 's/).*//')
    done
done < <(echo "$MASTER $REPLICAS")

eval "$cmd" | column -t

Comment: ```# ./test
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
./test: line 8: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

Comment: sorry, tried to format those for readability.. actually came out as a mess